# Strange data corruption with Buffer.BlockCopy C#

Tags: c#, arrays

**BACKGROUND**

I am writing a C# program which collects some information by data acquisition.  It's quite complex so I won't detail it all here, but the data acquisition is instigated continuously and then, on an asynchronous thread, my program periodically visits the acquisition buffer and takes 100 samples from it.  I then look inside the 100 samples for a trigger condition which I am interested in.  If I see the trigger condition I collect a bunch of samples from a pre-trigger buffer, a bunch more from a post-trigger buffer, and assemble it all together into one 200-element array.

In my asynchronous thread I assemble my 200-element array (of type double) using the Buffer.BlockCopy method.  The only specific reason I chose to use this method is that I need to be careful about how much data processing I do in my asynchronous thread; if I do too much I can end up over-filling the acquisition buffer because I am not visiting it often enough.  Since Buffer.BlockCopy is much more efficient at pushing data from a source array into a destination array than a big 'for loop', that's the sole reason I decided to use it.

**THE QUESTION**

When I call the Buffer.BlockCopy method I do this:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(newData, 0, myPulse, numSamplesfromPreTrigBuf, (trigLocation * sizeof(double));
```

Where;

**newData** is a double[] array containing new data (100 elements) (with typical data like 0.0034, 6.4342, etc ranging from 0 to 7).

**myPulse** is the destination array.  It is instantiated with 200 elements.

**numSamplesfromPreTrigBuf** is an offset that I want to apply in this particular instance of the copy

**trigLocation** is the number of elements I want to copy in this particular instance.

The copy occurs without error, but the data written into myPulse is all screwed up; numbers such as -2.05E-289 and 5.72E+250.  Either tiny numbers or massive numbers.  These numbers do not occur in my source array.

I have resolved the issue simply by using Array.Copy() instead, with no other source-code modification except for removing the need to calculate the number of elements to copy by multiplying by sizeof(double).  But I did spend *two hours* trying to debug the Buffer.BlockCopy() method with absolutely no idea why the copy is garbage.

Would any body have an idea, from my example usage of Buffer.BlockCopy (which I believe is the correct usage), how garbage data might be copied across?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume your offset is wrong - it's also a byte-offset, so you need to multiply it by `sizeof(double)`, just like with the length.

Be careful about using `BlockCopy` and similar methods - you lose some of the safety of .NET. Unlike outright `unsafe` methods, it does check array bounds, but you can still produce some pretty weird results (<strike>and I assume you could e.g. produce invalid references - a big problem</strike> **EDIT**: fortunately, `BlockCopy` only works on primitive typed arrays).

Also, `BlockCopy` isn't thread-safe, so you want to synchronize access to the shared buffer, if you're accessing it from more than one thread at a time.

Comment: Of course it is! I will try that when I come back from lunch and report my findings.  It sounds like you are correct.  Doh!

Comment: Yes, you were of course absolutely correct.  This is definitely one of those "why didn't I think of that"? Moments!

I considered the count but not the offset.  Really annoying!

Still, I am glad I have the understanding now.

Thanks for the thread-safe advice; I'm all good on that front.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `Buffer.BlockCopy` allows the source `Array` and destination `Array` to have different element types, so long as each element type is primitive. Either way, as you can see from the **mscorlib.dll** source code for [`../vm/comutilnative.cpp`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/2583ce936776a0eac31df904e41d5119840c203b/src/vm/comutilnative.cpp#L718-L803), the copy is just a direct imaging operation which never interprets the copied bytes in any way (i.e., as 'logical' or 'numeric' values). It basically calls the *C*-language classic, `memmove`. So don't expect this:

```
var rgb = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var rgl = new long[3];

Buffer.BlockCopy(rgb, 0, rgl, 0, 3); // likely ERROR: integers never widened or narrowed

// INTENTION?: rgl = { 1, 2, 3 }
// RESULT:     rgl = { 0x0000000000030201, 0, 0 }
```

Now given that `Buffer.BlockCopy` takes just a single `count` argument, allowing differently-sized element types introduces the fundamental semantic ambiguity of whether that single `count` argument would be counting the *total bytes* in terms or source or destination elements. Solutions to this might include:

1. Add a second `count` property so you'd have one each for *src* and *dst*; **(no...)**
2. Arbitrarily select *src* vs. *dst* for expressing `count`--and document the choice; **(no...)**
3. Always express `count` in bytes, since element size "1" is the (only) common denominator that's suitable to arbitrary different-sized element types. **(yes)**

Since (1.) is complex (possibly adding even more confusion), and the arbitrary symmetry-breaking of (2.) is poorly self-documenting, the choice taken here was (3.), meaning ***the `count` argument must always be specified in bytes***.

Because the situation for the `srcOffset` and `dstOffset` arguments isn't as critical (on account of there being independent arguments for each 'offset', whereby each *c̲o̲u̲l̲d̲* be indexed relative to its respective `Array`; spoiler alert: ...they aren't), it's less-widely mentioned that *these arguments are **also** always expressed in bytes*. From the documentation (emphasis added):

> [**Buffer.BlockCopy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy)
> <sup>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy</sup>
>
> ```
> Parameters
>   src         Array      The source buffer.
>   srcOffset   Int32      The zero-based byte offset into src.
>   dst         Array      The destination buffer.
>   dstOffset   Int32      The zero-based byte offset into dst.
>   count       Int32      The number of bytes to copy.
> ```

The fact that the `srcOffset` and `dstOffset` are ***byte-offsets*** leads to the strange situations under discussion on this page. For one thing, it entails that the copy of the first and/or last element can be partial:

```
var rgb = new byte[] { 0xFF, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0xFF };
var rgl = new long[10];

Buffer.BlockCopy(rgb, 1, rgl, 1, 8);    // likely ERROR: does not target rgl[1], but
                                        // rather *parts of* both rgl[0] and rgl[1]

// INTENTION? (see above)     rgl = { 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 0L } ✘
// INTENTION? (little-endian) rgl = { 0L, 0x0807060504030201L, 0L, ... }       ✘        
// INTENTION? (big-endian)    rgl = { 0L, 0x0102030405060708L, 0L, ... }       ✘
// ACTUAL RESULT:             rgl = { 0x0706050403020100L, 8L, 0L, 0L, ... }   ?
//                                                    ^^-- this byte not copied (see text)
```

Here, we see that instead of (perhaps) copying something into `rgl[1]`, the element at *index* 1, and then (maybe) continuing on from there, the copy targeted *byte-offset* 1 within the first element `rgl[0]`, and led to a partial copy--and surely unintended corruption--of that element. Specifically, byte 0 of `rgl[0]`--the least-significant-byte of a little-endian `long`--was not copied.

Continuing with the example, the `long` value at index 1 is a̲l̲s̲o̲ incompletely written, this time storing value '8' into its least-significant-byte, notably without affecting its other (upper) 7 bytes.

Because I didn't craft my example well enough to explicitly show it, let me be clear about this last point: for these partially-copied `long` values, the parts that are *not* copied *are not zeroed out* as might normally be expected from a *proper* `long` store of a `byte` value. So for the discussion of `Buffer.BlockCopy`, "partially-copied" means that the un-copied bytes of any multi-byte primitive (e.g. `long`) value are retained unaltered from before the operation, and thus become "merged" into the new value in some endianness-dependent--and thus likely (and hopefully) unintentional--manner.

To "fix" the example code, the offset supplied for each `Array` must be pre-multiplied by its respective element size to convert it to a byte offset. This will "correct" the above code to the only sensible operation `Buffer.​BlockCopy` might reasonably perform here, namely a little-endian copy between (one or more) source and (one or more) destination elements, taking care to ensure that no element is partially- or incompletely-copied, respective to its size.

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(rgb, 1 * sizeof(byte), rgl, 1 * sizeof(long), 8); // CORRECTED (?)

// CORRECT RESULT:            rgl = { 0L, 0x0807060504030201L, 0L, ... }       ✔

// repaired code shows a proper little-endian store of eight consecutive bytes from a
// byte[] into exactly one complete element of a long[].
```

In the fixed example, 8 complete `byte` elements are copied to 1 complete `long` element. For simplicity, this is a "many-to-1" copy, but you can imagine more elaborate scenarios as well (not shown). In fact, with respect to element count from source-to-destination, a single call to `Buffer.BlockCopy` can deploy any of five operational patterns: { [**nop**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP), **1-to-1**, **1-to-many**, **many-to-1**, **many-to-many** }.

The code also illustrates how concerns of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) are implicated by `Buffer.BlockCopy` accepting arrays of differently-sized elements. Indeed, the repaired example seems to entail that the code now inherently incorporates a (correctness-)​dependency on the endianness of the CPU on which it happens to be running. Combine this with the fact that realistic use-cases seem scarce or obscure, especially remembering the very real and error-prone partial-copying hazard discussed above.

Considering these points would suggest that the technique of mixing source/destination element sizes within a single call to `Buffer.BlockCopy`, while allowed by the API, should be avoided. In any case, use mixed element sizes with special caution, if at all.